# Convert NIM logic levels to LVDS

Tags: comparator, converter, lvds

For my application, I need to convert a negative voltage pulse which is in NIM logic ('1' is -0.8V, '0' is 0V) into LVDS signals. The other part of the problem is that a pulse width is approximately 0.5ns. Are there any solutions to this? What device/circuit configuration should I use?

Much appreciated!

Comment: Does the NIM to LVDS conversion need to preserve the pulse width, or just recognise that a pulse has been detected? E.g. is the LVDS output required to monitor the pulse width, or say just count pulses?

Answer (score 0):

In general, LVDS buffers can be also used to convert single-ended logic into a differential signal, by connecting the inverting input to a reference voltage between the two logic voltages. But in this case, the negative input voltages would require you to use a negative voltage for the buffer's GND, and this would be likely to move the LVDS voltage outside the valid input voltage range of your LVDS receiver(s).

Handling negative input voltages requires a comparator with support for split supplies, e.g., [TLV3801](https://www.ti.com/product/TLV3801). (This device requires a headroom of 1.5 V from V<sub>EE</sub>, so you need ±2.5 V supplies.)

[image: TLV3801]